# Internet Explorer file download prompt character encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, character-encoding, arabic

In Internet Explorer running an MVC 4 application, when downloading a file with an Arabic filename, the download prompt displays a filename which appears to be in the wrong character set. Please see the attached image.

[image]

If it's possible to alter the display of this filename how do I do it?

Comment: Programming related ??

Comment: @mlwn Are you questioning whether this is a suitable question for Stack Overflow? Because I would think it is.

Comment: What code have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `return File` method, try encoding the file name

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
{
    string attachment = string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", 
                                      Server.UrlPathEncode(fileName));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
}
return File(filePath, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
```